# how can I count some values for data in a table based on same key in another table in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

I have one table like bellow. Each id is unique.

| id | times_of_going_out |
| --- | --- |
| fef666 | 2 |
| S335gg | 1 |
| 9a2c50 | 1 |

and another table like this one ↓.　In this second table the "id" is not unique, there are different "category_name" for a single id.

| id | category_name | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S335gg | Games & Game Supplies | tk |
| 9a2c50 | Telephone Companies | os |
| 9a2c50 | Recreation Centers | ky |
| fef666 | Recreation Centers | ky |

I want to find the difference between destinations(category_name) of people who go out often(times_of_going_out<5) and people who don't go out often(times_of_going_out<=5).

** Both tables are a small sample of large tables.

・　Where do people who go out twice often go?
　・　Where do people who go out ６times often go?
Thank you

The expected result could be something like

| less than 5 | more than 5 |
| --- | --- |
| top ten “category_name” for uid’s with "times_of_going_out" less than 5 times | top ten “category_name” for uid’s with "times_of_going_out" more than 5 times |

Comment: The title says 'MySQL' but you tagged the question with 'google-bigquery', which one you are using?

Comment: sorry @ahmed I thought Bigquery is the same as MySQL(ya, that beginner). I am using Bigquery.

Comment: can you add the expected results table as well, indicating also the granularity

Comment: you just want to sum up everything by the category name ? please share the expected results of the above table and add the description

Comment: @trillion I add an image of what I need. Thank you

Comment: that is not the output please create a proper table like you have for the input data, based on the values that you are showing for the input

Comment: @trillion I am not sure if I understand you. How can I provide the table when I don't know the answer.

Comment: @アルサ is the solution working ?

Comment: @アルサ Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: @trillion I need the top 10 repeated place, the code gave me the places for less and above 5 times, however not the top repeated places.

Comment: i believe your question is not clear nor the output, you can ask another separate question and add the code and current table and the expected results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- combining data and aggregating total time_going_out
- creating the categories that you need : less than equal to 5 and more than 5. if you don't need equal to 5, you can adjust the code
- ranking both categories with top 10, using dense_rank(). this will produce the rank from 1 - 10 based on the total time_going out
- filtering the cases so it takes top 10 values for both categories

```
with main as (

select 
category_name,
sum(coalesce(times_of_going_out,0)) as total_time_per_category
from table1 as t1
left join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.id
group by 1
),

category as (

select
*,

if(total_time_per_category >= 5, 'more than 5', 'less than equal to 5') as is_more_than_5_times
from main
), 

ranking_ as (

select *, 

case when
 is_more_than_5_times = 'more than 5' then 
dense_rank() over (partition by is_more_than_5_times order by total_time_per_category desc)
        else NULL
    end AS rank_more_than_5,

case when
 is_more_than_5_times = 'less than equal to 5' then 
dense_rank() over (partition by is_more_than_5_times order by total_time_per_category)
        else NULL
    end AS rank_less_than_equal_5

from category
)

select 
is_more_than_5_times,
string_agg(category_name,',') as list
from ranking_
where rank_less_than_equal_5 <=10 or rank_more_than_5 <= 10
group by 1
```